# Virtualbox : port forwarding from guest to host is not working

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, port-forwarding

Under **VBOX** i ve a ubuntu based VM working under **NAT**

I'm used to do my port forward config unbder vbox like the following

```
Name     Protocol  IP host  Port host  IP Guest  Port Guest
myrule   TCP                3000                 3000
```

But when running my web app on the port 3000 ; i can't open it within browser in my host machine. (and it uns well inside my guest vm)

`ifconfig` shows the following in my guest vm :

```
ifconfig
enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.3.255
        inet6 fe80::b612:8769:ba28:6e2e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:42:89:7b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3354  bytes 2134154 (2.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2669  bytes 373394 (373.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 229607  bytes 231076789 (231.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 229607  bytes 231076789 (231.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And my **/etc/network/interfaces** file looks like this :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: Which host machine addresses did you try?

Comment: @Seth : i want to serve webb apps to localhost in Guest and just repoen them in host via (localhost / 127.0.0.1)

Comment: If you're only serving the content on localhost (on your guest) you won't be able to do this.

Comment: @Seth and what you may suggest ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need ti to be accessible on localhost? If not just make it available on a regular network interface. If you have security concerns setup a secondary interface with a different network mode.

Comment: i want to juste serve some web apps on my Guest (on port 4200 for example) and open them on my host browset (localhost:4200) ,, i ve learnt that NAT do it implicitly ; but i ve had some troubles and i ven t been able to open on Host ..@Seth